# stuck on xpath query

Tags: c#, xpath

I have an `xmlnodelist` which results in the below snippet

```
<updi:ProductName xmlns:updi="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:ProductIdentification:xsd:schema:01.04">Packet Processing Card (PPC) 16GB</updi:ProductName>
<ulc:AlternativeIdentifier xmlns:ulc="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:Locations:xsd:schema:01.04">
  <ulc:Authority>PID</ulc:Authority>
  <ulc:Identifier>ASR5K-PPC-K9=</ulc:Identifier>
</ulc:AlternativeIdentifier>
<ulc:AlternativeIdentifier xmlns:ulc="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:Locations:xsd:schema:01.04">
  <ulc:Authority>CPN</ulc:Authority>
  <ulc:Identifier />
</ulc:AlternativeIdentifier>
```

How can I grab the two authority and identifier tags?  I tried adding a root element but I have issues with the namespaces. The original namespace declaration is very large.

Comment: have you tried linq to sql

Comment: this is a snippet of a large xml document.  I am thinking of using linq to sql in the future but at this point I am sticking with xpathing a xml document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I doubt there's anything wrong with the XPath queries you've tried - more likely it's the namespaces that are tripping you up. There are a few ways to compensate/deal with this, ranging from "strip out all the namespaces" to using the `XmlNamespaceManager` - here's an example of that:

```
void Main()
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    var namespaceMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    namespaceMgr.AddNamespace("updi", "urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:ProductIdentification:xsd:schema:01.04");
    namespaceMgr.AddNamespace("ulc", "urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:Locations:xsd:schema:01.04");
    doc.LoadXml(xml);

    var authorityTags = doc.SelectNodes("//ulc:Authority", namespaceMgr);
    var identifierTags = doc.SelectNodes("//ulc:Identifier", namespaceMgr);
}
```

Assuming xml is:

```
    string xml = @"
    <ROOT>
    <updi:ProductName xmlns:updi=""urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:ProductIdentification:xsd:schema:01.04"">
    Packet Processing Card (PPC) 16GB
    </updi:ProductName>
    <ulc:AlternativeIdentifier xmlns:ulc=""urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:Locations:xsd:schema:01.04"">
    <ulc:Authority>PID</ulc:Authority>
    <ulc:Identifier>ASR5K-PPC-K9=</ulc:Identifier>
    </ulc:AlternativeIdentifier>
    <ulc:AlternativeIdentifier xmlns:ulc=""urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:Locations:xsd:schema:01.04"">
    <ulc:Authority>CPN</ulc:Authority>
    <ulc:Identifier />
    </ulc:AlternativeIdentifier>
    </ROOT>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The below will return all four nodes from your sample. I did have to wrap it in a root node for my testing. The `|` operator allows for the [union functionality.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx)

```
//ulc:AlternativeIdentifier/ulc:Authority | //ulc:AlternativeIdentifier/ulc:Identifier
```

I tested this using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with the [XPatherizerNPP](http://code.google.com/p/xpatherizernpp/) plugin, which I highly recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the trick:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("YourXmlFile");

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//*[local-name() = \"Authority\"]"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Authority: " + node.InnerText);
}

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//*[local-name() = \"Identifier\"]"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Identifier: " + node.InnerText);
}
```

Basically, `SelectNodes("//*[local-name() = \"Identifier\"]")` tells it to search for node in the xml with that name, regardless of namespace, etc.